# Why put Sprite in a baking recipe?

Tags: baking

My Apple Dumpling Recipe calls for Sprite or Ginger Ale to be added around dumplings before baking. What is the effect of the Sprite?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "added around dumplings"?

Comment: Indeed, I only connect "dumpling" with boiling, or sometimes steaming, never baking. Are you supposed to put the prepared dumplings in a pan and bake them in the oven? Before or after you boil them? Are you adding the sprite as the baking liquid in the pan when you bake?

Comment: It boils down and makes a syrup, while sort of steaming the dumping, if it's like other recipes I've seen : http://www.macspride.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/2004_WinnerPeach1_Peach_Enchiladas.pdf  (make fun of the name or the ingredients if you must, but these are really good)

Comment: @Joe Sounds like an answer! (Especially if you mention whether you can substitute sugar water or something; seems like maybe the carbonation isn't important.)

Comment: @rumtscho Apple dumplings are a baked dessert; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_dumpling

Comment: @coneslayer interesting. I have had similar food, but never heard of it being called a "dumpling".

Comment: @rumtscho Sounds like you're talking about Asian dumplings whereas the OP is talking about suet-type dumplings?

Answer (score 3):

The soda does a few things:

- adds moisture to steam the dumplings.
- cooks down into a syrup to make a sauce.

You can typically change out the soda, but you don't want to use a diet soda, as it won't thicken the same and some artificial sweeteners will break down when heated.  You don't just want to replace it with sugar water, as the acid in the soda will help to keep it from seeming overly sweet.

Comment: And this is different than the soda used in a coca-cola or 7-up cake.

Comment: Hm, do you think sugar+water+lemon (lemonade, I guess) would do? I'm not sure if the OP is just curious or trying to avoid buying soda, but there are definitely a lot of us who don't often have soda around.

Comment: @Jefromi : it might work, but I've never tried it.  I'd be inclined to make a syrup rather than just try to mix the sugar into the water ... maybe add some strips of citrus zest while cooking it down, then remove it.  Sprite has 38g of sugar in a 12oz can, and a pH of ~3.5 (averaging from multiple websites).